# gulp watch resulting in an endless loop after upgrading to gulp 4

Tags: gulp-watch, gulp-4

I have upgraded my gulpfile.js to gulp 4. `gulp dev` is working fine. But whenever I am editing any file the `reload` and `inject` tasks are entering into an endless loop.

My gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  symlink = require('gulp-symlink'),
  jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  useref = require('gulp-useref'),
  replace = require('gulp-replace'),
  templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
  gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
  gulpUtil = require('gulp-util'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  minifyCss = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  merge = require('merge-stream'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  inject = require('gulp-inject'),
  svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite'),
  postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
  autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
  webfonts = require('gulp-font');

/* DEV */
gulp.task('dev-serve', function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './'
  });

  gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', gulp.series('inject', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('inject', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/images/svg-sprite/*', gulp.parallel('svg-sprite', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', gulp.parallel('reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/*', gulp.parallel('reload'));
});

/* PROD */
gulp.task('prod-serve', function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './www'
  });

  gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass', 'build-html'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', gulp.parallel('inject', 'minify-scripts', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('inject', 'minify-scripts', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', gulp.parallel('copy-images', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/*', gulp.parallel('copy-fonts', 'reload'));
});

// SVG SPRITE
gulp.task('svg-sprite', function () {
  var svgPath = 'app/images/svg-sprite/*.svg';

  return gulp.src(svgPath)
    .pipe(svgSprite({
      shape: {
        spacing: {
          padding: 0
        }
      },
      mode: {
        css: {
          dest: './',
          layout: 'diagonal',
          sprite: 'app/images/sprite.svg',
          bust: false,
          render: {
            scss: {
              dest: 'app/styles/tools/_sprite.scss',
              template: 'app/styles/tools/_sprite-template.tpl'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      variables: {
        mapname: 'icons'
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// SCSS
gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
  gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(concat('style.css'))
      .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  });
  done();
});


// INJECT
gulp.task('inject', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['app/**/*.module.js', 'app/**/*.js', '!app/vendor/**/*.js'], {read: false}), {relative: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});


// HTML
gulp.task('build-html', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(replace('href="/app/"', 'href="/"')) // replace base href
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify().on('error', gulpUtil.log)))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});


// IMAGES
gulp.task('copy-images', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/images/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/images'));
});

// FONTS
gulp.task('copy-fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/fonts/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/fonts'));
});

// TEMPLATES
gulp.task('bundle-templates', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/**/*.html', '!app/index.html'])
    .pipe(gulpif('*.html', templateCache({module: 'jibbar'})))
    .pipe(concat('templates.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/tmp'));
});


// COMPONENTS
gulp.task('bundle-components', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/**/*.module.js', 'app/**/*.js', '!app/vendor/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});


// MERGE TEMPLATES AND COMPONENTS
gulp.task('merge-templates-and-components', gulp.parallel('bundle-templates', 'bundle-components'), function () {
  return gulp.src(['www/script.min.js', 'www/tmp/templates.min.js'])
    .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'))
});


// MINIFY SCRIPTS
gulp.task('minify-scripts', gulp.parallel('merge-templates-and-components', 'bundle-templates', 'bundle-components'), function () {
  return gulp.src('www/script.min.js')
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', gulpUtil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'))
});


// CLEAN TEMP
gulp.task('clean', gulp.parallel('bundle-templates', 'bundle-components', 'merge-templates-and-components'), function () {
  return gulp.src('www/tmp', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});


// RELOAD BROWSER
gulp.task('reload', gulp.series('inject'), function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});

//COPY IFRAME
gulp.task('copy-iframe', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/components/builder/iframe/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/app/components/builder/iframe'));
});

//COPY TINYMCE
gulp.task('copy-tinymce', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/vendor/tinymce/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/app/vendor/tinymce'));
});

//COPY VENDOR FILES
gulp.task('copy-vendor-files', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/vendor/angular.js','app/vendor/bootstrap.css','app/vendor/tooltip.css','app/vendor/jquery.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/app/vendor'));
});

//COPY APP IMAGES
gulp.task('copy-app-images', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/images/builder-image.svg','app/images/builder-dimensions.svg','app/images/info_icon.svg'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/app/images'));
});

gulp.task('dev', gulp.series(
  'inject',
  'svg-sprite',
  'sass',
  'dev-serve'
));

gulp.task('prod', gulp.series(
  'inject',
  'sass',
  'copy-iframe',
  'copy-tinymce',
  'copy-vendor-files',
  'copy-app-images',
  'build-html',
  'copy-images',
  'copy-fonts',
  'minify-scripts',
  'clean',
  'prod-serve'
));
```

The following image shows the endless loop
[image]

Can anyone please help me to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mark the tasks are in the gulpfile.js that I already shared.

Comment: In you 'dev-serve' and 'prod-serve' tasks I would change to all gulp.series instead of any gulp.parallel.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment above, this is probably a problem:

```
// RELOAD BROWSER
gulp.task('reload', gulp.series('inject'), function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});
```

In your watch statements you call inject and reload, and then in the reload task you call inject first which updates your html files (timestamp if nothing else) and so the html watch is retiggered which calls inject and reload again, etc.

Just use:

```
// RELOAD BROWSER
gulp.task('reload',  function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});
```

and change all your watch's to gulp.series.  Since you call reload last there is no need to call inject within the reload task again.

```
/* PROD */
gulp.task('prod-serve', function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './www'
  });

  gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass', 'build-html'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', gulp.series('inject', 'minify-scripts', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', gulp.series('inject', 'minify-scripts', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', gulp.series('copy-images', 'reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/*', gulp.series('copy-fonts', 'reload'));
});
```

and do the same for your 'dev-serve' task.

[Edit to fix will only run once]
Change to:

```
// RELOAD BROWSER
gulp.task('reload', gulp.series('inject'), function (done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
});
```

Also I'm pretty sure you need to use this form:

```
// RELOAD BROWSER
//--------------------------------------|
gulp.task('reload', gulp.series('inject', function (done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
}));
// another ) at the end above too.
```

See how the last anonymous function is included in the `gulp.series` call. You need to make that change in quite a few of your tasks.

Comment: thanks @Mark for your help. After making the suggested changes its not entering into the endless loop. But now the watch is running only once. Means if I change and .js file first time its reloading the browser but from the second change its not more reloading. Can you please help me to find whats the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my change above.  Usually the problem of a task running only once is that a previous task never signaled that it was complete - and so gulp will not start the new task.  In your case, at least the reload task needed to signal completion.  I added the done statements. Does that fix the issue?  You need to do the same to some of your other tasks, like 'dev-serve', 'prod-serve' and 'svg-sprite'.

Comment: And another edit above to properly use gulp.series().